# The Catholic Perspective concerning the Four Horsemen

Tags: catholicism, eschatology, revelation

Few Biblical symbols, allegories, or metaphors have fired the imagination more than the alleged Four Horsemen of the Apocalypse described all too briefly in Revelation 6:1-8.

Does the Catholic Church have an official interpretation of these verses?  And if so, how are the Horsemen interpreted by the Catholic Church?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fr. Herman Kramer's 1956 *[The Book of Destiny](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=4418)* is the most recent Catholic commentary on the Book of the Apocalypse. He covers the White, Red, Black, and Green Horses in part III, §A, chapters 1-4.

Apocalypse 6:2:

> The White Horse coming first on the scene is an allegorical figure of Conquest and of apparent victory over the Church. … the white horse was a symbol of victory won by the help of the gods … Some interpreters hold that the rider on the white horse is Christ Himself, (Iren. IV. 21/3; Victorinus and Andreas followed his opinion) and they remind us of chapter XIX. 12, where Christ appears riding on a white horse. Others hold that the white horse symbolizes the victorious Gospel, and the rider represents the preachers of the Gospel throughout the world.

3-4:

> A Red Horse, the symbol of war, appears.

5-6:

> A Black Horse appears. The description fits the personification of famine. Famine with exorbitant prices for food follows in the wake of war.

7-8:

> A horse of so strange a color appears, that the Seer calls it a "Green [or 'pale'] Horse". The color suggests to the mind a body decaying with pestilence. Death rides the horse. This personification of death presages utter depopulation or DEATH for this "FOURTH PART" of the earth.

See Fr. E. Sylvester Berry's 1921 [*The Apocalypse of St. John*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=4441) [pp. 69](https://archive.org/stream/theapocalypseofs00berruoft#page/68/mode/2up)-70 for a much briefer account than Fr. Kramer's.

Comment: So, is it the idea that the 4 horseman refer to the Catholic Church (ie Church in first quote and hence)?

Comment: @SLM They refer not to the Church, but to forces warring against the Church.