# Catholic interpretation of Revelation by John?

Tags: catholicism, exegesis, eschatology, revelation

Does the Catholic Church have the book of Revelation all fleshed out or do they teach it's sealed?

I'm aware of some elements, like the woman, for example, being Mary. If everything is fleshed out, then could someone point me to a good resource or briefly summarize its views?

Comment: cf. "[The Catholic Perspective concerning the Four Horsemen](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/62815/1787)"

Comment: I'm new to the community. People can down-vote questions? That's strange lol

Comment: If you mouse over the little down vote triangle, the explanation of what a down vote means will show you this text: *this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful* At the least, the question is getting close votes for being unclear.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE and the SE network.  If you'll review the [tour] and visit the [help], you can get an idea for how a Q&A site in the SE format is not a discussion forum.  There is a section in the [help] that shows [how to ask a good question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Don't worry, it took me a while to get a feel for that when I first began to participate on SE sites.

Comment: Speaking of unclear, I do not understand what you mean by this.  *Does the Catholic Church have the book of Revelation all fleshed out or do they teach it's sealed?*  What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

The best, most detailed Catholic commentary on [St. John's *Apocalypse*](http://drbo.org/drl/chapter/73001.htm) is

- *[**The Book of Destiny**](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=4418)* (1956) by Fr. Herman Kramer.

<sup>cf. the briefer, older commentary: [*The Apocalypse of St. John*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=4441) (1921) by Fr. E. Sylvester Berry</sup>

---

Commenting on [Apoc. 12:1](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=73&ch=12&l=1-#x) ("woman clothed with the sun"… etc.), Fr. Kramer writes:

> The woman of chapter twelve is not the Blessed Virgin Mary.
>
> […]
>
> According to the ancient Fathers, the human nature or character of the Church is here delineated, while in chapters four and five her divine nature and prerogatives were depicted.
>
> […]
>
> The twelve stars represent the twelve apostles; or they may be God's mystical number symbolizing the Christian nations, that as a contrast to the ten crowned horns of the beast, shall be the glory of the Church when the days of Antichrist approach.
>
> […]
>
> The moon under her feet has ever been understood to symbolize the unchanging and unchangeable character of the Church.

<sup>cf. [these excerpts of his commentary on Apoc. 12](https://isidore.co/forum/index.php?topic=125.msg348#msg348)</sup>

---

Also, [St. John's *Apocalypse*](http://drbo.org/drl/chapter/73001.htm) contains a [detailed description of the Catholic Mass](https://archive.org/details/ApocalypseMass).

Comment: I'll definitely read it, so I appreciate the tip.